# WIth Latin square design, is this situation valid?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, latin-square

I have no background in statistics so I would like to know whether I get it right:
**Q:** suppose I evaluate 3 Teaching methods in 3 schools and in 3 classes (First, Second and Third).
 I know that the sources of variability should be independent and here is the **problem**: if one school is particularly bad, all three classes in it will have bad results (it happened).
Is this the dependency?

Comment: `I know that the sources of variability should be independent ` explain.

Comment: Well there should be no interaction between them.

Comment: If you ran a full factorial experiment (3^3 or 27 conditions) then one should be able to separate out the effect of the method vs that of the school and class.  If you ran a small subset then maybe the effects will be confounded.

Comment: It appears that you have a fixed factor (teaching method) that is applied to classes which are nested within schools. As you point out, the observations within each school (and indeed within each class) will not be independent.  How do you evaluate the teaching methods ? Have you actually collected the data yet or are you designing the study now ?